# MySQL schema and CRUD queries for tags system

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema, relational-database

Lets imagine that I have videos and each video can have few tags (maximal is 10 tags per video).

I planned my SQL schema and it looks like this:

- `videos`: `id`, `title`, `path`,
- `tag_rels`: `id`, `tag_id`, `item_id` (it will point to `videos`.`id`),
- `tags`: `id`, `tag`;

Okay, seems fine to me.

Then I wrote `SELECT` that should get video, plus, tags for it.

```
SELECT `videos`.`id`, `videos`.`title`, `videos`.`path`, `tags`.`tag`
FROM `videos`
JOIN `tag_rels`
    ON `tag_rels`.`item_id` = `videos`.`id`
JOIN `tags`
    ON `tags`.`id` = `tag_rels`.`tag_id`
```

It's not tested or so because it's all in mind-level.

And the **huge problem** is `INSERT` query (queries, I guess).

As much as I understand:

- Query #1: insert video in `videos`. This will return primary key (`videos`.`id`), right?
- Query #2: select tag #1 from database and get it's primary key,
- Query #3: if there aren't such record (based on tag name (`tags`.`tag`), do an insert query and insert it. The goal is to get primary key of that tag,
- Query #4: insert entry in `tag_rels` with video's *pk* and tag's *pk*;

So, it's one query per video as it is, plus` 2 or 3 queries for **each** tag.

This means that if video has 10 tags and (worst situation) any of those tags aren't saved in database, it will cost me 1 + 10 * 3... em.... 31 query?!

There got to be a better way! Thanks a lot!

P.S. I don't want duplicate entries in the database and I would love to have column `used_in` to `tags` with video count that use the tag. In future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a like case for stored procedure.  Have the store produce take the video data, and the list of tags.  Then do Queries #1 to #4 inside.  It will be much faster since you don't have to move data back and forth.

Here's kind of what you would need.  It's only a starting point so don't expect it to compile much less run correctly, and you would need all 10 tags (I don't think mysql can take an array, but someone might know better).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertvideo (IN videotitle CHAR(20),IN videopath CHAR(20), IN tag1 CHAR(20),IN tag2 CHAR(20), IN tag3 CHAR(20)  )
    BEGIN
      DECLARE myid INT;
      DECLARE tagid INT;
      INSERT INTO videos (title, path) VALUES ( videotitle,videopath);
      SELECT id INTO myid FROM videos WHERE title=videotitle AND path=videopath;
      SET tagid=NULL;
      SELECT id INTO tagid FROM tags WHERE tag=tag1;
      IF tagid IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES (tag1);
        SELECT id INTO tagid FROM tags WHERE tag=tag1;
      END IF;
      INSERT INTO tag_rels (tag_id, item_id) VALUES (tagid,myid);
      SET tagid=NULL;
      SELECT id INTO tagid FROM tags WHERE tag=tag2;
      IF tagid IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES (tag1);
        SELECT id INTO tagid FROM tags WHERE tag=tag2;
      END IF;
      INSERT INTO tag_rels (tag_id, item_id) VALUES (tagid,myid);
      SET tagid=NULL;
      SELECT id INTO tagid FROM tags WHERE tag=tag3;
      IF tagid IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES (tag1);
        SELECT id INTO tagid FROM tags WHERE tag=tag3;
      END IF;
      INSERT INTO tag_rels (tag_id, item_id) VALUES (tagid,myid);
    END
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of that? I have no idea how procedures work - never used them before. Or, at least, some links...

Comment: Here's the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 1):

I think your calculation is wrong. You will need to execute 3 queries regardless of tags number.
1. `INSERT INTO Video ...`
2. `INSERT INTO tags(tag)

    SELECT * FROM

    (SELECT 'tag_1' as tag UNION SELECT 'tag_2' ...)a WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM tags b WHERE b.tag = a.tag)`
3.Assuming you have a unique index on (tag_id, item_id), `INSERT IGNORE INTO tag_rels( tag_id, item_id) SELECT tag_id, new_video_id FROM  tags WHERE tags.tag IN ([new tag_list])` (new_video_id - is Video.id you got after inserting a record into video)